# RcppEigen.h: No such file or directory during installation of ... RcppEigen on Centos 7

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp, eigen3

I'm not new to R but can't figure out what went wrong. I'm just trying to install RcppEigen package using `install.packages('RcppEigen')` and receive the above error.

The command below (issued by the installer) fails:

```
 g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -std=c++11 -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
```

I have installed both R-Rcpp and R-Rcpp-devel version 0.12.12 from EPEL repository as well as eigen3-devel v 3.2.5 (not sure whether it is required but anyway ...)

I cloned RcppEigen from [Github](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen) and tried to build in RStudio - the same error.

Makevars has **PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I../inst/include** but the compiler is invoked as below:

```
g++ -m64  -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/zer0hedge/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -std=c++11 -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
```

Comment: Any other message?

Comment: @F.Privé  No. Tried verbose with install.packages - didn't help. Please also see update - I can't build it from the cloned source code

Comment: Must be local to your box as we can test these packages via [R Hub](https://builder.r-hub.io/) on different platforms including CentOS, albeit only up to CentOS 6, as well as Fedora.  See [here](https://builder.r-hub.io/advanced) for the list.

Comment: I have two computers with CentOS 7 and it works fine. Try rebooting and making updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I had **PKG_CXXFLAGS** defined in `$HOME/.R/Makevars`.  It erroneously overrided **PKG_CXXFLAGS** in Makevars in src directory of the package and prevented compilation of C++ files